# Can I make a THREE.Material that has an opacity gradient along the Z axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using [three.js](http://threejs.org/) to render a scene with rainforest trees.  My camera is above the canopy level, and I want to make some features that are at ground level more visible.

So my idea is to have the trees be mostly transparent at the top, so you can see through the canopy, and more opaque toward ground level so the trunks are still visible.  I *could* do this by making the tree objects out of a number of stacked up sections, and use a more-transparent Material on the higher sections, but I'd much rather have a smooth opacity gradient.

My Z axis is pointing "upwards", so what I'm looking for, I guess, is a way to specify that the `THREE.Material`s I'm using are opacity 1.0 at `Z == groundLevel`, opacity 0.1 at `Z == groundLevel + 40` metres, and have the actual opacity at a given height interpolated based on those figures.

Is there a reasonable way to do that with existing `THREE.Material`s, or a simple modification to one of those?

Comment: Have you tried setting render fog? Seems like the simplest way.

Comment: I'm viewing from above the canopy, so I think fog would be the reverse of what I'm after.. plus the goal is to make the stuff under the trees easier to see.

Comment: Got it. I'm not familiar with the specifics of ThreeJS, but you can probably write a fragment shader that fades away the geometry at higher elevations. Sorry I can't give a more specific answer, but fragment shaders are what you need.

Comment: Thanks @positlabs , I think you're right, a custom shader is probably required.  ThreeJS offers various "materials", like Lambert and Phong materials to do those types of shading, a depth material to shade according to distance from camera, etc.  I was hoping someone had already written a Lambert-plus-opacity-gradient material, but if someone has I guess they don't check stack overflow very often :)